# CSS Custom properties in Ionic 4: background-hover

Tags: css, ionic4, theming

I'm trying to change the background colour on hover of an ion-item inside an ion-list. Working in ionic 4.

I've set up a list with *ngFor="let ....". Inside this, I put my ion-items. The list works perfectly. But I can't figure out why only some of the ionic provided CSS custom properties work. For example, I can't get --background-hover to do anything.

See the ionic doc page for the ion-item. This shows the full list of css custom properties: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item.

In .html file:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of animateItems; let i = index;">
     [-- contents of item --]
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In .scss file, this does not seem to work.

```
ion-item {
    --background-hover: #cccccc;
}
```

However, this does work:

```
ion-item {
    --background: #eeeeee;
}
```

Based on my understanding of the --background-hover CSS property, I expect the ion-item to turn grey when I hover over it with my mouse. Anyone know what I'm ding wrong, or why this does not work as per the ionic documentation.

Comment: Maybe a bug. ion-item's behavior also depends based on what is inside of it (like if you add other inputs like ion-select or ion-toggle etc - the component adds input "cover".). So please update your question with actual insides of the ion-item in your case

Answer (score 2):

I did some research into the library code, not sure if this is the correct answer but hopefully it'll help you get one.

In the item.scss, you'll find that `--background-hover` is being used when class `.ion-activatable` exists on the element:

```
@media (any-hover: hover) {
  :host(.ion-activatable:hover) .item-native {
    background: var(--background-hover);
    color: var(--color-hover);
  }

  :host(.ion-color.ion-activatable:hover) .item-native {
    background: #{current-color(tint)};
    color: #{current-color(contrast)};
  }
}
```

I test it by inspecting the element in Chrome Inspector, add the class to the element, hover it and it works. The question is how this class is being added to the element. You can search for it in the `item.js` and see that it's added based on the variable `canActivate` which is set by the `canActivate` function.

```
// If the item contains an input including a checkbox, datetime, select, or radio
// then the item will have a clickable input cover that covers the item
// that should get the hover, focused and activated states UNLESS it has multiple
// inputs, then those need to individually get each click
hasCover() {
    const inputs = this.el.querySelectorAll('ion-checkbox, ion-datetime, ion-select, ion-radio');
    return inputs.length === 1 && !this.multipleInputs;
}
// If the item has an href or button property it will render a native
// anchor or button that is clickable
isClickable() {
    return (this.href !== undefined || this.button);
}
canActivate() {
    return (this.isClickable() || this.hasCover());
}
render() {
    ...
    const canActivate = this.canActivate();
    ...
}
```

As the code suggests, it needs to be clickable or has cover. The element doesn't belong to the list of item has cover: `ion-checkbox, ion-datetime, ion-select, ion-radio` so the easiest way (without modifying the library code) is to make it clickable by adding an href. You can change your code to something like this and it should work:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of animateItems; let i = index;" [href]="item.href">
     [-- contents of item --]
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The href value can be `javascript:;` if you don't have one

Answer (score 2):

To Add to Truyen's answer, if you add a button="true" attribute to the :

`<ion-item button="true">...</ion-item>`

Then the hover variables actually take effect.